# Populating UITableView to show the newest data on top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a standard UITableView but I would like to rearrange how the tableView is populated. I would like this:

**Third Item Added**

**Second Item Added**

**First Item Added**

So the first data that is added in the tableView will be furthest down and the last data added on top. (Now the order is the other way around, last added furthest down).

Comment: Just iterate through your array from backwards and rearrange it.

Comment: What is your question? I know what you want to do but what do you need help with? Show some relevant code. Show what it is you need help with specifically.

Comment: Rather than *appending* an item *insert* it at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

for i in array {
    print(i)
}

// item1
// item2
// item3
```

Use the `reverse()` method on collections.

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
array.reverse()    

for i in array {
    print(i)
}

// item3
// item2
// item1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you fill your data.
If you use an array that you populate progressively, you can simply add items at index 0 (instead of using 'append' method, that add item at the end of the array), like this :

```
array.insert(item, atIndex: 0)
```

Or if you use an array containing static data, you can simply reverse all the array content like this :

```
array.reverse()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pulling down the data from Firebase. Don't think this medthow will work

Comment: When you pull the data from the server, place those results into an array and then reverse that array. Very straightforward stuff.

Comment: It will work. Share us some code if you want more help.